# Storing strings somewhere then writing out at once

Tags: python

I read that file I/O is slow and was looking at my own code that wrote to a file and found that I'm constantly calling write write write everywhere even for little things like a comma.

```
outFile.write(",")
```

So I figured maybe it'd be better if I stored all my characters somewhere (like, I don't know, 1 KB of characters or something before writing out).

How should I implement this? Do I just take a list and start appending strings to it, then do a join and write the resulting string out? Or maybe there's a better approach to it.

Comment: Where did you read this? What was the context? If you turn off all output statements, does you program run noticably faster? I assume you're talking about logging or something like that?

Comment: "it'd be better if I stored all my characters somewhere".  That's so obviously true that your programming language (Python), the underlying I/O libraries and the operating system all put characters into buffers before actually doing the file I/O.  This idea of "stored all my characters somewhere" is called "buffering" and is already being done for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `io` module's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html) for information on buffered I/O.  As S.Lott pointed out, there is already a buffer built into much of Python's built-in I/O objects, so you probably are already using it without your knowledge.

Comment: And in the unlikely case the builtin buffer *isn't* sufficient, the `io.StringIO()` and `io.BytesIO()` classes are the ones you're looking for to implement an in-memory buffer.

Comment: `StringIO` is in the `StringIO` module (also the `cStringIO` module in CPython, which is faster) in Python 2, rather than the `io` module.